# Grep file with pattern and count individual pattern matches in a file without changing order

Tags: grep

i need to get total matches from input.txt in digits using the words in pattern.txt, it needs to match between tags too.

this is the code im using and it works but output should be same sorting from input.txt and also remove the pattern from final output

```
grep -of pattern.txt input.txt | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}' > output.txt
```

pattern.txt:

```
sistersdrama.com
sisterssatellite.com
orientalsisters.com
```

input.txt:

```
<Model Make="www.sistersdrama.com" Displacement="1.6" HP="116" Year="2003"/>
<Model Make="sistersdrama.com="3.5" HP="298" Year="2003"/>
<Model Make="sistersdrama.com" Displacement="3.0" HP="200" Year="2011"/>
<Model Make="sistersdrama.com" Displacement="2.0" HP="257" Year="2002"/>
<Model Make="www.sisterssatellite.com" Displacement="2.5" HP="278" 
Year="2002"/>
<Model Make="www.sisterssatellite.com" Displacement="3.0" HP="224" 
Year="2009"/>
<Model Make="sisterssatellite.com" Displacement="1.8" HP="172" 
Year="2007"/>
<Model Make="sisterssatellite.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="186" 
Year="2001"/>
<Model Make="orientalsisters.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="179" 
Year="2006"/>
<Model Make="orientalsisters.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="207" 
Year="2013"/>
<Model Make="orientalsisters.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="246" 
Year="2008"/>
<Model Make="orientalsisters.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="244" 
Year="1999"/>
<Model Name="orientalsisters.com" Displacement="2.8" HP="244" 
Year="1999"/>
```

with the code used i get output.txt:

```
orientalsisters.com 4
sistersdrama.com 3
sisterssatellite.com 2
```

expected results with same order as pattern.txt, only digits and subtract 2:

```
1
0
2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `sort` and change `awk` from `'{print $2,$1}'` to `'{print $1}'`

```
grep -of pattern.txt input.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1}'
```

and if you want to subtract 2 from every result this would be

```
grep -of pattern.txt input.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1-2}'
```

**EDIT**

You have changed your question several times and every time there was cardinally different request. You should leave old version of your question as is because these radical changes  turns answers to be incorrect and irrelevant also. If you want different thing just create new post and ask there.

If you have multiple files with name pattern input*.txt (e.g input_1.txt input_2.txt input(whatever).txt) this should work:

```
cat pattern.txt |sed s/\\./\\\\\\\\./g|xargs -I {} grep -o "$(echo "Make=\"{}\"\|Make Model=\"{}\"")" input*.txt | sed -r -e 's/.*=\"(.*)\"/ \1 /g' > temp_agg.txt && cat pattern.txt|sed s/\\./\\\\\\\\./g | xargs -I {} grep -o {} temp_agg.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1-2}'
```

Comment: this seem to work but is there a way to add exclusions? because in input.txt some strings are www.sistersdrama.com and then they will be added as output also, i updated the question

Comment: try `grep -oxf pattern.txt input.txt  | uniq -c | awk '{print $1-2}' `

Comment: thanks! i have updated the question since i have multiple documents and need to match strings between tags, and is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: actually that worked perfect for half of my files! and it was also faster! is there a way to also include another regex in the script to match whats in pattern from another tag aswell:

    Displacement="orientalsisters.com"

this tag is not always on the same position as in input.txt example

Comment: so you want to filter out lines that contains attribute Displacement="test" ?

Comment: yes some strings in pattern are in other tags for example: Make="sistersdrama.com"  Displacement="sistersdrama.com"

also needs to be included in final output

Comment: can there be tag with both of them?

Comment: for example i changed "Make.*=\"{}\"") to ".*Make.*=\"{}\"")  and also edited sed with same regex

this matches: Make="test" and Make Model="test" 

it seem slower then before, is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: actually that did not work as it takes the whole line also

Comment: can there be a tag where will be both Make="sisterssatellite.com" Displacement="sisterssatellite.com"?

Comment: No need for now, just need to match Make="sisterssatellite.com" and Make Model="sisterssatellite.com"

please note Make Model= is on different line than Make="sisterssatellite.com"

Comment: there cannot be xml attribute 'Make Model' as there is a space into. can you show me an example

Comment: they are spread out in documents thats why i need to match so i can count, the layout is not stamdard so regex needs to match Make="sisterssatellite.com" and Make Model="sisterssatellite.com"

some lines start with <test="test" Make="sisterssatellite.com"> and others with <Make Model="sisterssatellite.com">

you understand with this example?

Comment: `cat pattern.txt | xargs -I {} grep -o "$(echo "Make=\"{}\"\|"Make Model=\"{}\")"  input*.txt  | sed -r -e 's/.*=\"(.*)\"/ \1 /g' > temp_agg.txt && cat pattern.txt | xargs -I {} grep -o {}  temp_agg.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1-2}'`

Comment: i tried it now but some of the URLs are stripped and will also be included as duplicate, example: sisterssatellite.com 99
sisterssatellitecom 99

sistersdr 44
sistersdrama.com 44

temp_agg.txt looks alright and no duplicate?  could it be by any chance the the code ignores the dot in the url? for example i have 2 similar url in pattern.txt sistersdrama.com and sistersdramadrama.com , but still make no sense because one URL can be totally stripped like sistersdrama.com is also duplicated as sistersdr in final output

Comment: does temp_agg.txt looks ok?

Comment: There was a problem with dot into the url  here is the final one:
`cat pattern.txt |sed s/\\./\\\\\\\\./g|xargs -I {} grep -o "$(echo "Make=\"{}\"\|Make Model=\"{}\"")"  input*.txt  | sed -r -e 's/.*=\"(.*)\"/ \1 /g' > temp_agg.txt && cat pattern.txt|sed s/\\./\\\\\\\\./g | xargs -I {} grep -o {}  temp_agg.txt | uniq -c | awk '{print $1-2}'`

Comment: i found another issue now that some are even counted doubled anyway for example i have in pattern orientalsisters.com and orientalsisters2.com then in output this will be counted as 2 and not 1. is there a way to modify so it matches case only?